# System.IO.IOException error

Tags: c#, exception, io

I wrote a program that reads from the serial port. No problem with the program run on the computer that has Visual Studio installed. Everything is OK. But when I copied release folder to another program and run it I have a error `System.IO.IOException`. I use this code to read data from serial port.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[42];
int readBytes = 0;
int totalReadBytes = 0;
int offset = 0;
int remaining = 41;

try
{
    do
    {
        readBytes = serial.Read(buffer, offset, remaining);
        offset += readBytes;
        remaining -= readBytes;
        totalReadBytes += readBytes;
    } 
    while (remaining > 0 && readBytes > 0);
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    Array.Resize(ref buffer, totalReadBytes);
}


UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
recieved_data = enc.GetString(buffer, 27, 5);                
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpdateUiTextDelegate(WriteData), recieved_data);
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Please add more details about the Exception. Knowing the exat message would help us a lot. Also, is that **all** your code? Are you using some non .NET library as well?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: 2 people need their voting rights revoked...  this question, as it stands, cannot possibly be useful to others..

Comment: Yes I am sure trippino

Comment: Most likely the port is not the same. I mean, COM1 on the first machine and COM2 on the other one. 
Anyway: please review the title of your post, and the body too.. probably you don't mean "another program", you mean "another machine", and also more detail about the exception, the dump of the ToString() method of the exception object for instance.

Comment: Sorry, I've removed my comment, btw, can you post the exception details and the port initialization code? Thank you

Comment: I check port when program is starting. Same program is running on my computer without error

Comment: I couldn't sent details because same program is running on my computer without error that has Visual Studio installed. I see this error `Sorunlu Olay Adı: CLR20r3
  Sorun İmzası 01: kantar.exe
  Sorun İmzası 02: 1.0.0.0
  Sorun İmzası 03: 51e6507f
  Sorun İmzası 04: System
  Sorun İmzası 05: 4.0.30319.18044
  Sorun İmzası 06: 5126f5a6
  Sorun İmzası 07: 4106
  Sorun İmzası 08: ec
  Sorun İmzası 09: System.IO.IOException
  OS Sürümü: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.16.7
  Yerel Kimlik: 1055
` other computer

Comment: catch the exception, put an MessageBox/dump, run the program on the other machine and post the exception.

Comment: I try to catch error with this code  `catch (IOException ex)
            {
                // Extract some information from this exception, and then 
                // throw it to the parent method.
                if (ex.Source != null)
                    MessageBox.Show("IOException source: {0}", ex.Source);
                throw;
            }` When run program I see just this message **IOException source: {0}** Nothing else

Comment: use `MessageBox.Show(string.Format("IOException source: {0}", ex.Message));`

Comment: OK I will try and return

Comment: Or `string.Format("IOException: {0}", ex)`, which will show the message, the stack trace, and the inner exception (if any).

Comment: yes @JimMischel's reply is better

Comment: [Error image please click](http://s21.postimg.org/500o5juzr/Untitled.jpg)

Comment: translate  **IOException source System.IO.IOException: Reached the end of file**

Comment: line 159: `totalReadBytes += readBytes;`

Comment: did you try with the property BytesToRead?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are reading more bytes than the port have transmitted, you should check the `BytesToRead` property to check how many they are.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
int readBytes = 0;
int totalReadBytes = 0;
int offset = 0;
int remaining = port.BytesToRead;

try
{
    do
    {
        readBytes = serial.Read(buffer, offset, remaining);
        offset += readBytes;
        remaining -= readBytes;
        totalReadBytes += readBytes;
    } 
    while (remaining > 0 && readBytes > 0);
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    Array.Resize(ref buffer, totalReadBytes);
}
```

Comment: This code see useful but sometimes program read just first 10 bytes or 12 bytes and does not expect to read all of them

Comment: Yes, this was only an example, you can change it. The important thing is that the third parameter of the Read function have to be always less than or equal to BytesToRead

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful:

http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/07/net-serialport-woes.html

http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/07/serialport-ioexception-workaround-in-c.html

But I haven't tested it.